# Get HTML elements in GWT

Tags: html, user-interface, gwt, uibinder

Like there is a getElementById() in JavaScript to get a HTML tag and in Android to attach to UI Element , is there a way in GWT do all the stylings in basic HTML and CSS and just use GWT for event handling ?

In other words, 
If I have in HTML :

```
<input type="button" id="refresh">
```

And in GWT :

```
Button b1 = new Button();
```

Can I bind these two together ?

~Thanks

Comment: Have you done *any* research yourself? This covered in every GWT tutorial, including the official one.

Comment: Is it through UIBinder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the right answer :-

```
Button button = Button.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("submit"));
```

is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Please do at least basic research before posting questions. Anyways here is your answer

```
RootPanel.get("refresh");
```